# PropertyChanged not raised when TextBox bound to a null property becomes null

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have this field and property

```
private long? _defautID;
public long? DefautID
{
    get => _defautID;
    set
    {
        if (_defautID != value)
        {
            _defautID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

linked to a textbox

```
<TextBox Content="{Binding 
                   Path=Expertise.DefautID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

When I add or remove a digit from the textbox, my property is updated and PropertyChanged is triggered without any problem.

But when I remove the last digit and my textbox becomes empty, my property is not updated (it keeps the last known value) and thus PropertyChanged is not triggered.

Is there any reason for this behavior ? And is there a workaround ?

PropertyChanged implementation :

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Did you verify (e.g. using the debugger) that the property is indeed set to `null` and just the notification is missing?

Comment: The property wasn't set to null, it kept the last known value. I need to rephrase my question because I explained that but it's not really clear. It'll help if someone stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `TargetNullValue` property of the binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding 
    Path=Expertise.DefautID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

This is required for the emtpy string in the `TextBox` to be successfully converted to `default(long?)` and for your property to be set.

Comment: This was indeed the solution. Weird how I never heard or found about this parameter, but it's gonna be really useful for me in the future. Thanks a lot !